# Do deleted files disappear over time?

Tags: rooting, data-recovery, data-transfer

I know that deleted files in database are not actually deleted instead of that, files are marked as 0. But how can we sure that no data is written on them?

I have a 128GB Xiaomi phone. I deleted my notes in May by accident. Since then, I tried to keep my phone storage under 100GB, thinking that deleted files which are marked as 0 are still in there. Now I have bought a new 128GB phone to recover my deleted files. I think it is only way to recover them.

My phone does not have root so I will transfer my data to new rooted phone at installation with USB OTG cable. Then I'm going to use programs which are needed to root, to recover deleted files. I hope I will save them. I'm trying from May and I saved money to buy a phone. Is there still hope or its hopeless.

Comment: You are mixing up database files and files in a File-System. As recent versions of Android use file based encryption both work totally different.

Comment: But i know that in d2d transfer even notes and app datas transfering too.

Answer (score 0):

If you have deleted the data and if you have not used your phone much after the data loss (adding more data or clicking new pictures or anything) you can be assured that data is not overwritten. If you're thinking of rooting Android phone, just a reminder, it should only be done in case of emergency as it nullifies your phone’s warranty and may not guarantee data recovery. Talking about purchasing new phone, you could have opted for genuine android data recovery software present online that could've recovered your files without rooting your old phone.

Comment: This is not true.  The OP says they have been using, just keeping the usage under 100Gb.  If there is software, then please elaborate on it.